# wso2 api manager new throttling tier

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

Can I define a new throttling tier like: "unlimited use for 30 days"?

```
 <wsp:Policy>
            <throttle:ID throttle:type="ROLE">30-days</throttle:ID>
            <wsp:Policy>
                <throttle:Control>
                    <wsp:Policy>
                        <throttle:MaximumCount> ? </throttle:MaximumCount>
                        <throttle:UnitTime> ? </throttle:UnitTime>

                    </wsp:Policy>
                </throttle:Control>
            </wsp:Policy>
```

EDIT: the goal is to make "expire" the subscription of a certain API for a certain user after 30 days...is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can't specify your requirement with the two parameters ***MaximumCount*** and ***UnitTime*** in a policy file. The solution as of now for your requirement would be to publish your API using the predefined ***Unlimited*** tier in the API Publisher, and manually remove it from the API gateway by changing the life cycle state of the API from ***Published*** to ***Created*** after a month's time.

Comment: But if I change from Published to Created it is not going to be visible to other users...or am I wrong? I only wanted to make "expire" the subscription to a particular API for a particular user